# Text only on left side on mobile version

Tags: android, css, mobile

I made my site mobile with a mobile stylesheet , but the text in a list is now only showing on the left side as if I double tapped on the text.
I'm using android 4.2 and this is in the standard Cyanogenmod browser, but it is the same in other browsers.

I already tried:

```
width:100%;
word-wrap:normal;
text-wrap:none;
```

HTML:

```
<div id='bottom'>

<hr>

<span id='lastEdit'>
<?php echo 'Laatst gewijzigd: '.date('d F Y:',filemtime('index.php')); ?><br>
</span>

<ul>
    <li>- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</li>
    <li>- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</li>
    <li>- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</li>
</ul>

<span id='nextEdit'>Wat nog komt:</span>

<ul>
    <li>- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</li>
    <li>- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</li>
    <li>- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</li>
</ul>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
span#lastEdit,span#nextEdit
{
font-weight:400;
width:100%;
word-wrap:normal;
text-wrap:none;
}

ul
{
list-style-type:none;
padding-left:5px;
width:100%;
word-wrap:normal;
text-wrap:none;
}

div#bottom
{
clear:both;
font-size:50px;
width:100%;
}
```

Still nothing changes!

Thanks in advance.

[image: It's in Dutch]

Update: It does work on IOS (Safari and Chrome)

Comment: Sorry, what _should_ it be doing instead?

Comment: @MLeFevre filling the whole screen and not just a part

Comment: Ah got you, could you possibly share the HTML you're using as well?

Answer (score 1):

The default value of `text-align` is `left`. What you are seeing is expected behavior.

If you want to see different results, change it. There is `left`, `right`, `center`, `justify`. etc.. See MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align

Comment: However, it does work on IOS (both Safari and Chrome)

Comment: @Tuinopo80 Can you please provide some relevant HTML/CSS?